# CSV data got truncated by SAS

Tags: csv, import, sas, truncate

I'm using SAS University Edition 9.4

This is my CSV data.

```
     ,MGAAAAAAAA,3,A0000B   2F1
11111,ﾊｱﾝ12222234222B56122,4,AA  0000
     ,ﾃｽﾄﾃﾞｰﾀ,5,AACHY 2410F1
     ,ﾃｽﾄﾃﾞﾀﾃｽﾄﾃ,5,AACHYF2
```

This is my infile statement.

```
data wk01;
 infile '/folders/myfolders/data/test_csv.txt'
 dsd delimiter=','   
 lrecl=1000 missover firstobs=1;
 input firstcol  :$  secondcol    :$ thirdcol    :$ therest    :$;
run ;
```

I expected my result like this.

[image]

But after executing SAS, What I got is as below (the yellow highlight indicates which row/column have its data being truncated by SAS)

[image]

For example, the first row's second column is `MGAAAAAAAA` but SAS's outut is `MGAAAAAA`

Could you please point out what am I missing here? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of your variables are longer than the 8 bytes you are allowing for them. The UTF-8 characters can use up to 4 bytes each. Looks like some of them are getting truncated in the middle, so you get an invalid UTF-8 code.

Just define longer lengths for your variables instead of letting SAS use the default length of 8.  In general it is best to explicitly define your variables with a LENGTH or ATTRIB statement.  Instead of forcing SAS to guess how to define them based on how you first use them in other statements like INPUT, FORMAT, INFORMAT or assignment.

```
data wk01;
  infile '/folders/myfolders/data/test_csv.txt' dsd dlm=',' truncover ;
  length firstcol $8 secondcol $30 thirdcol $30 therest $100;
  input firstcol secondcol thirdcol therest;
run ;
```

Comment: for some weird reason, this was failing earlier when the OP had posted a slightly different question and dataset which he removed eventually. This  standard method actually now works with this dataset. I agree that the solution I proposed is totally over-engineered.

Comment: @PythonRSAS Yes, this answer solves the problem when importing by CSV format. But my old issue has to be deal with by your solution (need to use ksubstr instead of substr though). There is no easy way importing a fixed width format file with UTF-8 character by SAS.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is a mixed encoding problem. What's essentially happening is that after the first 5 characters which are in ASCII, it changes to UTF8. The commas are getting mixed up in this soup and your standard delimiter gets a bit confused here. You need some manual coding like this to deal with it I think :

```
data wk01;
  infile "test.csv" lrecl=1000 truncover firstobs=1;
  input text $utf8x70.;

  firstcomma =  findc(text,',', 1);
  secondcomma =  findc(text,',', firstcomma + 1);
  thirdcomma =  findc(text,',', secondcomma + 1);
  fourthcomma =  findc(text,',', thirdcomma + 1);

  length firstcol $5;
  length secondcol $30;
  length thirdcol $1;
  length fourthcol $30;

  firstcol= substr(text,1, firstcomma - 1);
  secondcol = substr(text, firstcomma + 1, (secondcomma -firstcomma-1 ));
  thirdcol = substr(text, secondcomma + 1, (thirdcomma - secondcomma - 1));
  fourthcol = substr(text, thirdcomma + 1);
run;
```

Probably there is a cleaner way to do it, but this is the quick and dirty method I could come up at 2 AM :)

Comment: Hi, actually I came up with this solution too, anyway thanks alot for your comment.

Comment: This fixed the truncation problem by setting longer lengths for the 2nd and 4th columns.  The rest of the complexity is not really needed.

Comment: Could you please 'unaccept' this answer as I would like to remove this. @Tom proposed answer actually works now (though making the lengths longer did not work for you earlier - not sure what you changed in the dataset now).

Comment: @PythonRSAS No need to remove it. By the way, because Tom's answer is more accurate to the situation, please let me unmark this answer and give it to Tom's. Thanks alot for your help.